# Poor real-time SVM performance

Tags: python, scikit-learn, computer-vision, classification, svm

I'm working on a gesture recognition program. My dataset consist of hands in different poses. Im trying to use an SVM to get a baseline before I jump into neural networks. My dataset has 6 classes I'm trying to classify, with around 1000 examples for each class.

I used an 80-20 split. 80% for training and 20% for testing. After running the SVM model on the testing set I'm plotting a confusion-matrix which is showing me that it's getting ~96% Precision , ~96% Recall, and ~96% F1-Score.

Here are some examples of my training set images:

```
https://imgur.com/gwRSx3C
https://imgur.com/UxUPj5t
https://imgur.com/wXcaUq6
```

Webcam Images

```
https://imgur.com/j97cTnp
https://imgur.com/6QDHMAD
https://imgur.com/C9DELsr
```

Here are some images from my webcam.

I'm stoked naturally. Only downside is that when I hook up my model to a webcam for real-time inference, the model is borderline butt. Anyone have any ideas as to why it might be doing so badly if the precision, recall, f1 are so high?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 possible answers

1. Your model is overfitting.
2. The distribution from which your training and testing dataset are drawn from is not the same as data from your webcam.

---

I think your problem is that your webcam data is significantly different from your training data.

To debug your model you should do the following

- Compare the training data with your webcam images.
- Use a validation set, and only use the testing set at the last possible moment.
- Reconsider your features.
- Train with some of your webcam data as well mixed into the dataset.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. What do you mean use your testing set as the last possible moment? And wouldn't incorporating webcam data into my dataset give me false results? (Model learn to recognize me.)

Comment: Can you post an example photo from your webcam and from your dataset please. As for the train/test split, the most correct way is to use a three fold split, train/validation/test. That way you can be careful not to overfit. You always check your results with validation. When you are satisfied with your model then you get its final performance metric using the testing set.

Comment: Added some images to my post, thanks for taking the time to reply. I'll try mixing webcam images into my dataset and post results.

Comment: It seems the angle and the size of the hand is very similar. It should be working. Can you make it easier for your algorithm by placing a black background instead of the light. It might be confusing your skin with the bright background.